# How to check if user roles have changed?

Tags: symfony

I want to check if the user's roles have changed.

Look at this example : I'm an administrator and I want to change the roles of an another administrator (`ROLE_MEMBER_ADMIN` to `ROLE_USER`). But the member's roles changes only if he disconnect and reconnect.

Does the `isEqualTo` method of `EquatableInterface` is the solution? How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement it on your own. This sounds a bit like a user log.

You can make a new table where you log all events related to the userid. Then you can log every event.

After that you can write a function which checks wheather there is a change for a user.

Comment: I'll set a listener to check if roles have changed... Have you an idea to to it?

Answer (score 0):

In your User Entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable, EquatableInterface {

    /* took out getters/setters/ members declaration for clarity */

    /**
    * @see \Serializable::serialize()
    */
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            $this->roles
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            $this->roles
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user) {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->email !== $user->getEmail()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->isActive !== $user->isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        // check roles
        // http://www.metod.si/symfony2-reload-user-roles/
        if (md5(serialize($this->getRoles())) !== md5(serialize($user->getRoles()))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

It should do it, tested with PHP 5.3.27, PHP 5.4.X has some issues with serialization.

Hope this helps.